# Trying to get an inner join across 3 tables to work

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

```
"SELECT TT.SubmitDate AS SD, TT.AssignedEmp as AE, TT.JobNum as JN, 
        TT.BegMile as BM, TT.EndMile as EM, TT.TotMile as TM, TT.TandT as TA, TT.Daily as DA,
        TI.InTime as IT, TI.OutLunch as OL, TI.InLunch as IL, TI.OutTime as OT, TI.TotalTime as TO,
        WO.JobName
 FROM TimeTracking TI
 INNER JOIN TransportTable TT 
 ON TI.TimeSheetNum = TT.TimeSheetNumber
 INNER JOIN WorkOrderNum WO
 ON TT.JobNum = WO.JobNumber
 WHERE TT.AssignedEmp='$empname' AND TT.SubmitDate >= '$start' AND TT.SubmitDate <='$end' 
 ORDER BY TT.SubmitDate";
```

It gives me this error message:

```
SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error
(missing operator) in query expression 'TI.TimeSheetNum = TT.TimeSheetNumber 
INNER JOIN WorkOrderNum WO ON TT.JobNum = WO.JobNumber'., SQL state 37000
in SQLExecDirect
```

The query works fine if I remove either of the two joins, so I know the issue isn't with the joins individually... am I missing something simple?

Comment: It's showing simply syntax error(missing operator).So,better to look out carefully from top.I hope you know syntax about inner joins to get more than two tables data.

Comment: What happens when you remove the entire `where` clause? What types are `TimeSheetNum(ber)` and `JobNum(ber)`? Off Topic but to my opinion, it's best to be consistent with column naming. It doesn't matter if you use `Num` or `Number` but do yourself *(and others)* a favor and pick **one**.

Comment: Still same issue if I remove the where clause. TimeSheetNum(ber) and JobNum(ber) are both ints. And yes, I did screw up with the column names and is something I've been meaning to go back and fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access requires parentheses in the `FROM` clause of queries which include more than one join.  If possible use the Access query designer to set up the joins --- the query designer knows where to place the parentheses to keep the db engine happy.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (TimeTracking TI
    INNER JOIN TransportTable TT 
    ON TI.TimeSheetNum = TT.TimeSheetNumber)
    INNER JOIN WorkOrderNum WO
    ON TT.JobNum = WO.JobNumber
```

If the joins work in a similar simple query, you can add your `SELECT` fields, the `WHERE` conditions, and the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @HansUp - thx. I've learned something new again and the day is still young <g>.